# TensorFlow 1.5.0-rc0: error using `tf.app.flags`

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following flags were defined in a `misc_fun.py` file to include machine and directories info:

```
import tensorflow as tf
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
# definitions
flags.DEFINE_string(
    'DEFAULT_IN',
    '~/PycharmProjects/myNN/Data/',
    """Default input folder.""")
...
```

It worked fine in TensorFlow 1.0 - 1.4 versions (with Pycharm). After updating to TensorFlow 1.5.-rc0, the following error occurred:

Usage:

```
from misc_fun import FLAGS
FLAGS.DEFAULT_IN = FLAGS.DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD  # change default input folder
```

Error:

```
UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD before flags were parsed.
```

However `print(FLAGS)` worked fine, which gives:

```
misc_fun:
  --DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD: default download folder for large datasets.
    (default: '/home/username/Downloads/Data/')
  --DEFAULT_IN: default input folder.
    (default: '~/PycharmProjects/myNN/Data/')
...
```

I tried `FLAGS = flags.FLAGS(sys.argv)`, resulting in the following error:

```
UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line flag 'f'
```

Although there is a workaround using the class object, I wonder what could be the problem here.

Comment: What exactly are the contents of your `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With 1.5.0-rc0 the Tensorflow maintainers have switched tf.app.flags to the flags module from [abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py). Unfortunately, it is not 100% API compatible to the previous implementation. I worked around your problem with something like

```
remaining_args = FLAGS([sys.argv[0]] + [flag for flag in sys.argv if flag.startswith("--")])
assert(remaining_args == [sys.argv[0]])
```

before accessing the FLAGS object the first time.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried adding the following line below.

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f', '', 'kernel')

This solution is different from others in that it is simple and easy to try. You just need to add this into your code, and it doesn't change your system. Please let me know if this solution helps solve other people's problems.

The reference for this solution is from a Chinese website: https://blog.csdn.net/qq_39956625/article/details/80500291

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has a few answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `FLAGS(sys.argv, known_only=True)` to parse all related flags (the ones defined using tf.app.flags.DEFINE_xxx). This will release any other args that are not known. Useful if you have some command line arguments that are not related to TF.